# Inverse Laplace Transform Using Piecewise Continuous Functions

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Compute the inverse transform of $\displaystyle F(s) = \frac{e^{-2s}}{s^2}$ using unit step functions. Write your answer as a
piecewise continuous function.

I don't understand how to do this with piecewise functions.

Comment: To clarify, the equation is e^(-2s)*s^(-2).

Comment: Is that the function that I take the transform of? How would I write the answer as a piecewise continuous function?

Comment: Is $F(s)$ given by $F(s)=e^{-2^s}/s^2$or is it $F(s)=e^{-2s}/s^2$?

Comment: It is $F(s)=e^{-2s}/s^2$.

Comment: The part that I do not understand is converting to piecewise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$G(s) = \frac{e^{-2s}}{s^2}$$

We know that

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left ( \frac{1}{s^2}\right) = tu(t)$$

and that

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left ( e^{-as}F(s)\right) = f(t-a)u(t-a) \tag{time shift property}$$

Therefore,

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left ( G(s)\right) = (t-2)u(t-2) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t \leq 2 \\
      t-2 & t > 2
   \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! I'm a little confused about applying this method to another problem, however. This time, $F(s)=s(e^{-\pi s}+e^{-2\pi s}){({s^2}+4)^{-1}}$

Comment: Would you break it into two different inverse Laplace Transforms, one for each $e$?

Comment: @H.Rumo Yes, that's a valid approach.